# Use Pandas, to extract a column and add each index to a sentence, then increment sets of strings based on a condition. Python or Pandas better?

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv working, (the file.write below prints to text file but uses the data in the csv) but i was wondering how I convert the code to the Pandas framework, everytime I try to print (really i need to write to file this errors or I can get it to work to call a paticular column,index then add to a string.) Is pandas preferred for this method, or should I use the original code below? I have pandas working to read a csv file but its the file.write I do not.

As a bonus question I see in Pandas the use of lambda, but i want to increment "titleA to titleA-1" all titleA, but titleB's increment to -2's.
import csv
import ipaddress

```
with open('foo.csv','rt')as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    Data = list(data)
print(Data)
file1 = open('titles.txt','w')

for item in range(len(Data)):
  file1.write('this is titleA:' +  ' ' + str(Data[item][0])  + '\n')
  file1.write('this is titleA:' +  ' ' + str(Data[item][0])  + '\n')
  file1.write('this is titleB:' +  ' ' + str(Data[item][0])  + '\n')
  file1.write('this is titleB:' +  ' ' + str(Data[item][0])  + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it got it working doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.read_csv (r'foo.csv', header=0)


test = df['title'] = df.apply(lambda x: f'The title is {x["title"]} is {x["date"]}', axis=1)
print(test)
output_file = open('test_file.txt','w')
output_file.write(str(test))
output_file.close()
```

New Guy